# Customizing OIM Default user form interfaces: Implementing Custom Cascading LOVs

Tags: java, javabeans, oracle-adf, oim, lov

Below is the details of my tasks.

1. Define component binding for the User Type field and any parent component of Job Code, for example, form root panel.
2. Implement the model for Job Code LOV component by ensuring the following:

   I) The model must take into account the current value of the User Type field.

   II) For af:selectOneChoice, you must implement a method that returns List.

   III) For af:inputListOfValues, you must implement a method that returns an instance of oracle.adf.view.rich.model.ListOfValuesMode.
3. Implement valueChangeListener for the User Type field. Set the autosubmit property to true for the User Type field. valueChangeListener must update model of Job Code LOV component with the current value of the User Type field. In addition, valueChangeListener must re-render the form so that Job Code LOV component is updated with the current list of values.

**Note:** I need to implement all tasks by bean class in backing bean scope. I am new on this technology.

Please help me to implement this logic.

Comment: This has a pretty well laid out step-by-step http://oraclestack.blogspot.com/2015/06/creating-cascaded-lookups-on.html